# Background color does not fill entire div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that is a panel, and I want to apply to the body a black background color, when I do that it left around 100 px white space

[image: image div]

I think that happens because in my css I defined

```
.Stock{
    min-height:600px;
    height:600px;
}
```

but I want the div to be that big it matches the perfect size, if I cut this css the size changes, I want to maintain the size and have that white space filled, how can I do that ?

**here is the html of the specific div**

```
 <div class="panel panel-default Stock">
                    <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-custom clearfix">
                        <div>
                            Controlo de stock
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a href="#Avisos"><img alt="" class="warningImg" height="20" src="../warning.png" width="20"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <h4 id="numberWarnings"></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body ProdutosTodos">
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a>                                <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeIceTea"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeCroissant"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeKitKat"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeKinderBueno"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeWatter"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeBubbleGums"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 SeccaoProduto">
                            <p class="productName"></p>
                            <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
                            <p id="quantidadeCheaps"></p><a class="editar" href="#">editar</a> <a href="#" id="eliminar">eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form action="" class="form-horizontal" id="formularioEdicao" name="formularioEdicao">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1">
                            <a href="#" id="PageBack"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-offset-1 col-md-2" for="">Produto</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input class="form-control" id="EditarNomeProduto" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-offset-1 col-md-2" for="">Quantidade</label>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
                                <input class="sliderProducts" type="range">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" id="GuardarEdicao">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: Have you tried:
'.Stock{
min-height:600px;
height:auto;
}'

or 
'.Stock{
min-height:600px;
height:100%;
}'

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make the min-height and the height the same. Try this:

```
.Stock {
  min-height: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

or maybe:

```
.Stock {
  min-height: 600px;
  height: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is coming from `.panel` in `panels.less`:

```
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px; // <-- Your background-color will not fill 100%
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

The image you have shown does not look like 100px. Try setting `margin-bottom: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS. It will fix your problem:

```
.panel {
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 600px;
  height: 700px;
}
```